# i have to click twice to make the right function in Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

i have to click two times in my label to do the correct thing that i want.
the first time that i click works, then when i click it show something different

```html
<div class='form-row'>
  <div class='col-md-12'>
    <label class='labeldata' style='cursor: pointer;'>" + settaData(i.periodi) + "</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.labeldata').click(async function(e){
    sessionStorage.scambio= e.target.innerText; // get the value
    sessionStorage.crx= 11111; // run the routine of my pgm
    
    Bottone('B1001');
})
```

Comment: try to use $('.labeldata').bind('click', function(){// your code});

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For example: Is `Bottone` an asynchronous function? If yes, why are you setting `async` without `await`ing the function then?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.labeldata', async function(e) {
  sessionStorage.scambio = e.target.innerText;
  sessionStorage.crx = 11111;
  Bottone('B1001');
});
```

Comment: thank you i think that is a problem of my pgm